# Chart js not showing negative y axis

Tags: chart.js

I have seen a lot of answers to this type of question but I have still not found a solution. This is my bar chart:

[image]

All I would like is to be able to set the y axis scale to display from a negative number, and for the the labels not to overlap the chart.

I have the following options:

```
var options = {
    barValueSpacing : 5,
    barDatasetSpacing : 0,
    scaleBeginAtZero: false
}
```

but it doesn't set the starting point as -2, I am not sure why.

Have looked at https://jsfiddle.net/1fkc5jt7/ which does exactly what I want but it does not work on my chart for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `,`

```
var options = {
    barValueSpacing : 5,
    **barDatasetSpacing : 0,**
    scaleBeginAtZero: false
};
```

Comment: Sorry - just a typo. That does not change anything. Still behaves the same.